# Delete Operation in Laravel Through ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am Unable to delete a record. I want to do this through Ajax call. Is my code right?

This is my **index.blade.php** file

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function deleteStudent(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'/student/'+ student.id,
            type:'POST',
            data:{_method: 'delete' },
        });
    }
</script>
<button type ="button" class="btn btn-small btn-danger" onclick="deleteStudent({{ $value->id }})">Delete this student</button>
```

This is my destroy Function in **StudentController.php**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    // delete
    $stud = \app\Student::find($id);
    $stud->delete();

    // redirect
    \Session::flash('message', 'Successfully deleted the student!');
    return \Redirect::to('student');
}
```

This is my **route.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::resource('student', 'StudentController');
});
```

Comment: You'll probably need to pass csrf token as well. What specifically is not working for you and what kind of error do you get?

Comment: not getting any error. Delete operation is not working. Is my code correct?

Comment: Should be good if you don't get any errors.

Comment: If you are using Ajax, you need to make sure that you use the csrf token as devk suggester. Look at this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf you need to put in the in header with a meta tag so all ajax calls can use it.

Comment: Since you are performing a `post` operation it would be better to delete the user in the  `store` method

Comment: @linktoahref that is not a good idea i think..!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Comment: Change the type of your ajax method to `type: 'DELETE'`

Comment: @linktoahref He is using method delete. See `data:{_method: 'delete' },`. Most browsers don't natively support methods other than GET and POST, so sending additional parameter (like `_method: 'delete'`) to indicate the method is a workaround.

Comment: What is the ajax response you get in the network tab

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update ajax request code to include csrf token for it:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Add This token before your Function

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {            
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')        
    }    
})
```

Edit your Function:

```
function deleteStudent(id) {
             var project_url="{!! URL::to('/')!!}";// use base url 
            $.ajax({
                url:project_url+'/student/'+id,
                type:'POST',
                data:{_method: 'delete' },
            });
        }
```

Comment: why you copied my answer. as i have put the similar answer yesterday and you copied the same. That is not a good thing. do efforts to get points not copy and paste from others

Answer (score 1):

Update ajax request code to include csrf token for it:

Add CSRF meta tag:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Include this code before ajax function:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {            
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')        
        }    
    });
```

Made some modificatons in your ajax function as below:

```
function deleteStudent(id) {
                 var project_url="{!! URL::to('/')!!}";// use base url 
                $.ajax({
                    url:project_url+'/student/'+id,
                    type:'POST',
                    data:{_method: 'delete' },
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can  update your code:

```
$stud = \app\Student::find($id);
$stud->delete();
```

To

```
\app\Student::find($id)->delete();
```

Or

```
\app\Student::destroy($id);
```